# usb 3 SS cable type to IP64 panel connector

Tags: usb, circuit-design, cables, usb-c

I am designing an industrial equipment on which a USB 3.0 connection is required (for speed reasons).
The electronics being in an IP64 box, I am forced to transfer the USB-C/3.0 connector to a panel connector.
So I wonder what type of cable to use to make the link between the main card and the mini USB-C panel connector card (ffc/fpc, ribbon, custom & twisted, connectorless...).

I don't have a PC on hand to look at how the USB 3 connector on the front panel is made.

Any opinions or recommendations?

Thanks !

Comment: I'm not sure why this hasn't been voted to be closed, as this question is clearly asking for product references, which you guys seem to hate.  Since it hasn't been closed, though, I will answer with a product reference...

Comment: I didn't ask for a product reference, I know how to deal with it. I just needed someone's opinion or experience on deporting a USB 3.0 link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the high speeds required for full speed USB 3.0 communications, the USB C implementation needs very specific tolerances for it's cabling, with the high speed communication lines having shielded and very tight-twisted wire pairs.  The higher current supply specification for powering devices also requires larger gauge wire than normal USB cables can provide, so USB 3.0 cables really need custom cabling solutions.

For most short distance situations, you could probably just use CAT6 cable, but it wouldn't provide enough conductors to pass all of the signals included in a USB C connector.  A quick search also shows bulk cable available for USB 3.0 communications, but my [initial result](https://web.archive.org/web/20190121174946/http://www.l-com.com/usb-usb-30-compliant-bulk-cable) only shows cable with two high speed pairs and power in the cable.  For very short lengths in a custom design, you may be able to use ribbon cable, routing the differential pairs next to each other, with a ground line on either side of each pair.

There are also ready-made [extension cables](https://www.adafruit.com/product/4218) and [adapters](https://www.digikey.com/short/pr9cnb) available that are designed to be panel mounted.

Comment: I am free to choose the connectors. As it will be dedicated to USB host for a USB flash drive, I plan to use a standard solution such as fpc. Unfortunately, the custom cable will be too expensive for the user. The current will be limited upstream OR on separate connectors.